# Pytorch: gradient computation fails when in-place operation follows certain functions

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Consider the following piece of code:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
a = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
b = nn.Tanh()(a)
# b = nn.Linear(1,1)(a)
b *= 1
# b = b * 1
b.sum().backward()
```

Running the code results in RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1]], which is output 0 of TanhBackward, is at version 1; expected version 0 instead.
```

However, if I change `Tanh()` to `Linear(1,1)` **or** change `b*=1` to `b=b*1` (as in the commented lines), the code will run successfully and get the correct gradient.

Why is that?

My environment:

- Python 3.8.5 (anaconda) on Windows
- Pytorch 1.8.0, running on CPU

Answer (score 3):

I just found some text from the Pytorch official site:

> **In-place correctness checks**
>
> Every tensor keeps a version counter, that is incremented every time it is marked dirty in any operation. When a Function saves any tensors for backward, a version counter of their containing Tensor is saved as well. Once you access self.saved_tensors it is checked, and if it is greater than the saved value an error is raised. This ensures that if you’re using in-place functions and not seeing any errors, you can be sure that the computed gradients are correct.

Source: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-correctness-checks

According to this, an in-place operation may or may not break the gradient computation, depending on the actual situation.

Therefore, as long as the code contains in-place operations, it should not be a surprise when (as what is observed in the question) changing something in the context magically fixes the gradient computation.

Also according to the same passage, in-place operations may disrupt the gradient calculation even if they do not break it, in which case the speed of gradient calculation may be decreased. So it seems like a good strategy to avoid *any* in-place operation.